# C# - CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' (EF - code first)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I've seen some of the answers in here, but nothing helped resolving the problem.

I'm following Microsoft ITAcademy tutorial on MVC Jumpstart and they teach by an example that uses `EF Code-First` approach.

When I'm running the application, I'm getting an error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Conference-20150930151714;Integrated Security=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
```

I do not post all the code in here, since it is a work through Microsoft tutorial line by line.

It fails when I call one of the controller that is supposed to have data retrieved from the database:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Speakers.ToList());//fails here with described exception
}
```

This is how `Database` is initialized in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;    
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ConferenceContext>(new ConferenceContextInitializer());
        //the rest of code....// 
    }
}
```

This is `ConferenceContext` class:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
public class ConferenceContext : DbContext
{
    //public ConferenceContext() : base("name = DefaultConnection") { }
    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Speaker> Speakers { get; set; }
}
```

This is a piece of code for adding dummy data to `Database`:

```
public class ConferenceContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ConferenceContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ConferenceContext context)
    {
        context.Sessions.Add(
            new Session()
            {
                Title = "I want Spaghetti",
                Abstract = "The life and times of spaghetti lover",
                Speaker = context.Speakers.Add(
                    new Speaker()
                    {
                        Name = "John Doe",
                        EmailAddress = "john.doe@test.com"
                    })
            });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Can you explain me where the database is supposed to be created?

Should I have special permissions on my `SQL Server` for that or it is just enough to create a database in `App_Data` folder?

Will I be able to do create Database at all on my work `PC`?

Comment: Could you try to uncomment this line and see what will happen

    '//public ConferenceContext() : base("name = DefaultConnection") { }'

Comment: Go into SSMS and create a database in the SQLEXPRESS instance. Your current connection string expects it to be called "aspnet-Conference-20150930151714" but you might want to just call it "aspnetdemo" or something simple. If you can't create it in management studio, you have a permission issue. Another option is to use LocalDb https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202(v=SQL.110).aspx

Comment: The thing is the database has to be created automatically when code runs. I do not have to create it myself. I think, I do not have permission to create a database

Answer (score 3):

You need to give your account a global server permission to create database on the server.

Comment: So, basically, I will need to contact my Network Admins to give me the permission? Is database created in SQL Server?